# How to cut bytearray?

Tags: python, arrays, list, byte

I have a bytearray, and when I list the array, I get the following data: `(b'v10 \ xc73 \ x9a & \ x9edv \ x19 \ xc3B \ xbf \ x95 \ xc8 \ xd8 \ x9dN \ x8f \ xe9 \ x90J \ xax> r1 \ x1d \ xa7 \ x1fU \ x90 \ XE2 (| p \ XF1 \ x02 \ xbdw \ XB8 \ xb9 \ xf3 \ x0e \ xb2n \ xc7 ',)`.

And I need to decrypt this data. But the decryption function only receives data, for example, `b'v10 \ xc73 \ x9a & \ x9edv \ x19 \ xc3B \ xbf \ x95 \ xc8 \ xd8 \ x9dN \ x8f \ xe9 \ x90J \ xax> r1 \ x1d \ xa7 \ x1fU \ x90 \ xe2 (| p \ xf1 \ x02 \ xbdw \ xb8 \ xb9 \ xf3 \ x0e \ xb2n \ xc7'` without `()` and `,`

What can I do?

Comment: The `()` and `,` are **not part of the bytearray**. They indicate that you **do not simply have a bytearray**, but instead a tuple that contains one bytearray within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing we have

```
data = (b'foo',)
```

then this `data` is **not a bytearray**, nor is it a `bytes` object:

```
>>> type(data)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Because it is a tuple, we may extract that element:

```
>>> data[0]
b'foo'
>>> type(data[0])
<class 'bytes'>
```